# Can Scriptish inject scripts into other chrome: windows?

Tags: firefox, greasemonkey, scriptish

As we know Scriptish has the support for the `chrome:` scheme (although disabled by default), but it failed to inject a user script into other chrome: window (for example, download window, or about window).

Writing a script using `@include chrome://foo/bar` only works when the browser window opens this page as a tab, but not for a new window with this URL, except the browser window itself, use `@include chrome://browser/content/browser.xul` does work.

Is there any way to let Scriptish do this just like what `uc` does? Or is Scriptish just designed like this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have resolved it.

Scriptish will insert a toolbar button to browser windows. And every time it wants to inject a script, it checks if the target is alive and if it has Scriptish's UI, if not, it just return.

As a result, although it supports `chrome` scheme, it only inject scripts into browser windows and chrome page in tabs.

I edited `modules\utils\Scriptish_injectScripts.js`, removed this check at line 29, now it can inject scripts as their `@include` meta data.

Comment: Show code (before and after), and list any error messages you got before.

Comment: Line 29 of function `Scriptish_injectScripts(options)` , original as `if (!chromeWin || !chromeWin.Scriptish_BrowserUI) return;` after as `if (!chromeWin) return;`   

No any error messages before edition.